# android ViewModelFactory with hilt

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

I am first trying android `ViewModel` and `Hilt` DI

As i understand from below link, to initialize ViewModel with a value on run-time i should use `ViewModelFactory`

[Use a ViewModelFactory](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-view-model/#7)

```
//ViewModel
class ScoreViewModel(finalScore: Int) : ViewModel() {
   // The final score
   var score = finalScore
   init {
       Log.i("ScoreViewModel", "Final score is $finalScore")
   }
}

//ViewModelFactory
override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
   if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(ScoreViewModel::class.java)) {
       return ScoreViewModel(finalScore) as T
   }
   throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class")
}


//Fragment
viewModelFactory = ScoreViewModelFactory(ScoreFragmentArgs.fromBundle(arguments!!).score)
```

And to use ViewModel with hilt i should use `@ViewModelInject` as explained in below link

[Hilt and Jetpack integrations](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-jetpack)

```
//ViewModel
class ExampleViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(
  private val repository: ExampleRepository,
  @Assisted private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
) : ViewModel() {
  ...
}

//Activity / Fragment
@AndroidEntryPoint
class ExampleActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
  private val exampleViewModel: ExampleViewModel by viewModels()
  ...
}
```

But how to use `Hilt` with `ViewModelFactory`?

It seems the answer is in the `@Assisted` but i can't figure out how

How to tell hilt i like it to inject repository interfaces to ViewModel while still allowing ViewModelFactory to initialize the ViewModel with parameters on run-time?

Comment: This article might provide a clear sharing of how to work with this issue https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/passing-intent-data-to-viewmodel-711d72db20ad

Answer (score 30, accepted):

courtesy of @Elye, next articles helped a lot. I recommend a read.

[Passing Activity Intent Data to ViewModel through Injection](https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/passing-intent-data-to-viewmodel-711d72db20ad)

[Injecting ViewModel with Dagger Hilt](https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/injecting-viewmodel-with-dagger-hilt-54ca2e433865)

It seems that mostly Factory is not needed since mostly `viewmodel` initial parameters are taken from previous fragment and can be accessed via `SavedStateHandle` which is automatically injected if marked as @Assisted

To set-up hilt i used the following code-labs tutorial

[Using Hilt in your Android app](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-hilt/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0)

Then, `viewModel` injection is done automatically using only the next code

Note that as noted by fabioCollini [here](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/1906), it seems `savedStateHandle` can also get values from [safe args](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data) by simply placing argument name as the key. In fact, that is what i did in the following example. ps: In an attempt to make the safe args be more "safe", i did try to replace the `SavedStateHandle` with `ItemsFragmentArgs` hoping it will work but the app did not compile. I do hope it will be implemented in the future (and if already, please let me know)

```
//ItemFragment file
@AndroidEntryPoint
class ItemsFragment : Fragment() {

    private val viewModel: ItemsViewModel by viewModels()

    //use viewModel as you would. No need to initialize.
}

//Module file - if you have any repository, remember to bind it 
//or provide the exact implementation as noted in code-labs
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
@Module
abstract class DatabaseModuleBinder {

    @Binds
    abstract fun bindGlistRepository(impl: FirestoreGlistRepository): GlistRepository

}


//ItemsViewModel file - lastly, anotate as follows and take your arguments 
//from savedStateHandle (for safe args, use variable name as key)
class ItemsViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(private val glistRepo: GlistRepository,
                     @Assisted private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle) : ViewModel() {

    private val glistLiveDate = glistRepo.getGlistLiveData(
        savedStateHandle.get<String>("listId")!!
    )

..
}
```

Hope it helps anyone and if any mistake, please let me know

Comment: My Problem was, I was using viewmodel in Fragment and on Fragment i didn't mention @AndroidEntryPoint. I mentioned that on Activity but not on Fragment.

Comment: To use safe-args in the view model you can implement something like I've shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64814055/1842900

Comment: `@ViewModelInject` and `@Assisted` are deprecated now.

Answer (score 7):

Pass your ScoreViewModelFactory into built in ktx-extension of viewModel. Also you can consume Activity/Fragment arguments by using SavedStateHandle itself with defaultViewModelProviderFactory.

```
/*
Gradle Dependencies
def lifecycle_version = "2.2.0"
def hiltLifeVersion = "1.0.0-alpha01"
def hiltVersion = "2.28.1-alpha"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:$lifecycle_version"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hiltVersion"
implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha01"
implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-work:$hiltLifeVersion"
implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-common:1.0.0-alpha01"
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$hiltVersion"
kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:$hiltLifeVersion"
*/

import androidx.fragment.app.viewModels

@AndroidEntryPoint
class ExampleFragment : Fragment(R.layout.example_fragment) {

    //internally using defaultViewModelProviderFactory 
    private val viewModel : ExampleViewModel by viewModels()

    //or you own viewmodal factory instance --> scoreViewModelFactory
    private val viewModel : ExampleViewModel by viewModels { scoreViewModelFactory }

}

class ExampleViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(
    private val repository: ExampleRepository,
    @Assisted override val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
) : ViewModel() {

    //bundle args -> String, Int, Parcelable etc.. 
    private val arg1LiveData: MutableLiveData<String> = 
                         savedStateHandle.getLiveData("arg1", "")

}
```

In built ktx-extension of Fragment viewmodel

```
@MainThread
inline fun <reified VM : ViewModel> Fragment.viewModels(
    noinline ownerProducer: () -> ViewModelStoreOwner = { this },
    noinline factoryProducer: (() -> Factory)? = null
) = createViewModelLazy(VM::class, { ownerProducer().viewModelStore }, factoryProducer)
```

Comment: scoreViewModelFactory from where?

Answer (score 2):

In Jilt 2.44, at least, there is no `@ViewModelInject`. To inject into the constructor of a `ViewModel` the ViewMolde needs to be annotated with `@HiltViewModel` and for the constructor you can just use `@Inject`.

```
@HiltViewModel
class MyViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val navigationHelper: NavHelper
) : ViewModel()
```