# How to use SavedStateHandle and navigation Safe Args

Tags: android, performance, parameter-passing

I have two options to pass data between fragment, the navigation's safe args and viewModel's SavedStateHandle, what's the difference between them and how to use them in the correct place?

Answer (score 15):

There are few discussions about this issue.
[android ViewModelFactory with hilt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62650736/android-viewmodelfactory-with-hilt)
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/136967621

For me, most obvious solution is to use something like

```
SafeArgs.fromSavedStateHandle(savedStateHandle)
```

But for now, I am using string keys.

Comment: `MyFragmentArgs.fromSavedStateHandle(savedStateHandle)` is available as of safe args 2.4.0

Comment: @Tom `2.4.0-rc01`  if more correct, stable version is not here yet https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#version_240_2

Comment: @user924 It went stable yesterday :)

Comment: @Tom this is funny :) does it work correctly with the latest studio and gradle plugin versions?

Comment: @user924 I assume it does, I cannot test it unfortunately as my project as a dark age dependency that is preventing me from moving past 2.3.0-alpha04

Answer (score 7):

If you are using hilt you can wrap the incoming arguments in the fragment (and other components) like so

```
open class BaseFragment : Fragment() { // Inherit your fragment from this

    override fun setArguments(args: Bundle?) {
        if (args != null) {
            if (args.getBundle(BUNDLE_ARGS) != null) {
                super.setArguments(args)
            } else {
                super.setArguments(Bundle(args).apply {
                    putBundle(BUNDLE_ARGS, args) // Wrap the arguments as BUNDLE_ARGS
                })
            }
        } else {
            super.setArguments(null)
        }
    }
}
```

and then for the view model, you can inherit from something like that

```
open class ArgsViewModel(private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle) : ViewModel() {

    val arguments get() = savedStateHandle.get<Bundle>(BUNDLE_ARGS)

    @MainThread
    inline fun <reified Args : NavArgs> navArgs() = NavArgsLazy(Args::class) {
        arguments ?: throw IllegalStateException("ViewModel $this has null arguments")
    }
}
```

And then use it just like you would use safe args

```
class FooViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(
    @Assisted savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
) : ArgsViewModel(savedStateHandle) {

    private val args: FooFragmentArgs by navArgs()
}
```

Comment: We're having a problems with this implementation. It can sometimes cause stackoverflows, when Android framework tries to write Bundle to Parcel.

Comment: I didn't notice any crash-reports related to this implementation, but I don't doubt that there could be issues. OS writing to the bundle causing stackoverflow doesn't sound like an implementation issue of this particular method, but there you go. In either way there will be a better way of doing things with androidx-navigation-2.4.0, so stay put - I'll try to remember to update the answer

Comment: Ah sorry, didn't notice `Bundle(args)`. In our case someone plainly put `args` to `args`. Your answer is ok then.