# How to pass navigation argument into ViewModel using Dagger Hilt?

Tags: android, dagger-hilt, android-architecture-navigation

I have a Single Activity App consisting of two List-Detail fragments

My navigation function looks like this:

```
private fun navigateToDetail(noteId: String?, transitionView: View) {
    val action = NotesFragmentDirections.actionNotesFragmentToNoteDetailFragment(
        noteId,
        transitionView.transitionName
    )
    val extras = FragmentNavigatorExtras(transitionView to transitionView.transitionName)
    findNavController().navigate(action, extras)
}
```

Here is my ViewModel in DetailFragment:

```
@HiltViewModel
class DetailViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _state: MutableStateFlow<DetailState> = MutableStateFlow(DetailState())
    val state: StateFlow<DetailState> = _state.asStateFlow()

    init {
        savedStateHandle.get<String>("note_id")?.let { noteId ->
            getNote(noteId.toLong())
        }
    }
    ...

}
```

I have 2 cases, either I send an ID as an argument, in which case the parts fragment is filled in.
Or I send null to open an empty parts screen. But for some reason in savedStateHandle the value is always null.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand the `structure` from your codes. However, I can show an example usage.

**SharedViewModel**

```
class SharedViewModel(private val stateHandle: SavedStateHandle) : ViewModel() {
    var data = stateHandle.getLiveData<String>("key")
}
```

**FragmentA**

```
findNavController().currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.set("key", data)
findNavController().navigate(R.id.fragmentB)
```

**FragmentB**

```
sharedViewModel.data.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
    
})
```

**Note**

```
private val sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel by activityViewModels()
```

Comment: Do I have to use the SharedViewModel approach?
Since I'm currently using separate ViewModels for each fragment.
I thought the SaveArgs plugin automatically converts passed arguments to Bundle which are passed to savedStateHandle which initializes the Dagger Hilt

Comment: You can manage it with SavedStateHandle. But alternative https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63752526/how-to-use-savedstatehandle-and-navigation-safe-args