# what's the difference between "by viewModels()" and @Inject lateinit var viewModel

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

I want to know the difference  between "by viewModels()" and @Inject lateinit var viewModel.
let's assume that I change the screen mode vertical to horizontal.
When I use the "by viewModels()", the viewModel is same viewmodel before I got.
But when I use the "@Inject lateinit var viewModel", it's a new viewmodel.
I want to know why I get a different viewmodel.

```
    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModel : MainViewModel

    // private val viewModel : MainViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun initActivity() {
        initView()
        if(!viewModel.isInitialized){
            viewModel.setInitStatus(true)
            viewModel.getSearchImageList()
        }
    }
```

```
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: DefaultRepositoryImpl
) : ViewModel() {

    var isInitialized = false
}
```

Comment: Add your `ViewModelProviderFactory` with question . Also take a read at https://stackoverflow.com/a/62705023/4168607

Comment: You can't use `@Inject` in combination with a viewmodel, and I am surprised that your device didn't crash. You have to use 'by ViewModels()' because the creation of your viewmodel is managed by the framework and hilt.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want your ViewModel to be injected into Activity, the recommended way is to use `by viewModels()` or `by activityViewModels()` extension functions provided by KTX. They do all of the required injection automatically behind the scene. Note: don't forget that they both are lazy-evaluated! You can read more here: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel
2. I'm not 100% sure why you get a different ViewModel every time you use field injection with Dagger. However, it could be a Dagger scope problem. So, a custom scope applied to the ViewModel can lead to Dagger creating a new instance of your ViewModel every time you try to inject it into a new place. You can read more about Dagger scopes here: https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/dagger-android#dagger-scopes
3. It is also recommended when creating ViewModels with dependencies to use `ViewModelProvider.Factory` instead of constructor injection. Read more here: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel/viewmodel-factories