# unable to create an instance of class ViewModel with value pass in viewmodel constructor

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, dagger-hilt

Note - I am using dagger hilt.
I am trying to initailze ViewModel using `private val viewModel by viewModels<RegisterViewModel>()`
but it is giving me error that view model cannot be initalize.

if i pass value in costructor

```
@HiltViewModel
open class RegisterViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val registerRepository: RegisterRepository,
    private val dataStoreManager: DataStoreManager
) : BaseViewModel() {}
```

i get error **java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.kotlinframework.debug/com.kotlinframework.ui.register.view.RegisterActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.kotlinframework.ui.register.viewmodel.RegisterViewModel**

```
@InstallIn(ViewModelComponent::class)
@Module
abstract class RepositoryModule {

    @Binds
    abstract fun provideLoginRepository(impl: LoginRepositoryImpl): LoginRepository

    @Binds
    abstract fun provideRegisterRepository(impl: RegisterRepositoryImpl): RegisterRepository

}
```

If i dont pass any value in viewmodel constructor

```
@HiltViewModel
open class RegisterViewModel @Inject constructor() :  BaseViewModel() {}
```

It works successfully.

Comment: Maybe this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62650736/android-viewmodelfactory-with-hilt

Comment: What about your DataStoreManager object, is it provided somewhere?

Comment: I solved it by adding @AndroidEntryPoint to each activity and fragment.